# Firebase Check if user already exists

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried running the following and it does not work. What am I doing wrong to check the Firebase server if the user has already used the email?

```
           FIRAuth.auth()!.createUser(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!) {(createUser, error) in
        if error != nil { 
            FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: self.userEmailTextField.text!, password: self.userPasswordTextField.text!)

            //Display logged in

            let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarController") as UIViewController
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else {
            //Display an alert message
            self.displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: "Email already in use. Please see the login page.")
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer below code.

**Code:**

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) {
  (user, error) in
  if (error) {
    // Email is already in use.
  } else {
    // Create new user successfully
  }
}
```

[Handle Firebase iOS Auth Errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors)

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have the spaces before and after the  `?`

Answer (score 2):

Firebase already does this for you. Erase the sign in method and just run the create user method using an email that already exists and `FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse` will be returned. Check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth) out for more info

Comment: @alienware00 you're welcome.. Don't forget to up vote and mark as answer if it helped resolve your issue.. Happy coding :)

Comment: But what if I just want to verify that the user exists or not, because if it doesn't exists, i might not want to create a new auth entry, but merge with an existing auth (if I find this new logged in user already have an account with the same email, i will merge with that instead of creating another account).

Comment: @VanDuTran That's why you have a database of users. Make a query to your database looking for that particular user and check to see if the snapshot exists.